# Firefox not opening when IF statement is true batch

Tags: batch-file, firefox, service, phpmyadmin

I have this little piece of code here, which opens MySQL and Apache and then asks the user if he wants to open PHPMyAdmin as well, but it doen not quite do this, as it just skips onto the next lines.

```
@echo off

net start mysql
net start Apache2.4

set /p openPMA=Would you like to open PMA? (y/n)

if %openPMA%=="y" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

echo Press any key to stop the Servers
pause >nul

net stop mysql
net stop Apache2.4
```

How can I sove this?

I basically want to start the servers, ask the user if he wants to open PMA as well - if so do so, else continue - and then stop the servers if the user presses a key.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, quotes are taken literally. That's the way batch works, unlike unix/Linux shells.

So `if %openPMA%=="y"` should be `if /i "%openPMA%"=="y"` if you want to avoid to enter `"y"`.

(Note that quotes still have a special meaning and are useful, for example to run commands containing spaces in their paths, but no special processing is done when it comes to strings)

Comment: ...and add `/i` to make case-insensitive. @OP: you've not specified what you are entering. The issue *appears* to be that simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will leave the variable unchanged in a `set /p`. Consequently, it would have no value which leads to a syntax error on the `if`. Quoting both sides provides some measure of safety. It would be possible to default to `y` by using a `set "openpma=y"` before the `set/p`.